# Interior of $\mathbb{R\setminus N}$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the interior of $\mathbb{Q} $ is the empty set since every point contain neighborhoods that contain at least one irrational number. Also, the interior of $\mathbb{R} $ is just $\mathbb{R} $. But what would be the interior of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N} $ ?

Comment: $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb N$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb{R\setminus N}$ is open, so its interior is just itself.

Answer (score 4):

That set is open in $\mathbb R$, being a union of open intervals; so it is equal to its interior.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\Bbb N$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, so $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb N$ is open and hence its own interior.